# Checking whether 2 list has same value or value,index

Tags: python, list

I have this 2 list

```
a = [3,9,1,4,5]
b = [7,2,1,0,1]
```

Im trying to print a line based on some condition (same value or same index and value in 2 list), and the output should be

```
"Same Value(for duplicate number)"
"Same Value + Index(for duplicate number and same index)"
```

I tried using iteration and if like this

```
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        if x == y:
            if (a.index(x) == b.index(y)):
                print("Same Value + Index")
            else:
                print("Same Value")
```

but somehow the output shows this :

```
Same Value + Index
Same Value + Index
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

Or maybe is there any easier way for this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are seeing the printout twice is that `list.index` returns the index of the *first* occurrence of a value in the list, not the "current" one. So when your second list is at index 4 and the first one is at index 2, `b.index(1)` returns 2, not 4, and the second printout happens.

You should keep track of your current location:

```
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    for j, y in enumerate(b):
        if x == y:
            if i == j:
                print("Same Value + Index")
            else:
                print("Same Value")
```

If all you care about is the number of entries that match each condition:

```
both_match = len(set(enumerate(a)) & set(enumerate(b)))
```

Getting the same number of "anything matches" is marginally trickier. You can use `collections.Counter` to get the numbers just right:

```
ca = Counter(a)
cb = Counter(b)
value_match = sum(ca[k] * cb[k] for k in ca.keys() & cb.keys())
```

Comment: Oooh i see,I didnt know if .index only return first occurence of a value.
Therefore, thank you! this solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is faulty in looking up the number:

```
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        if x == y:
            if (a.index(x) == b.index(y)):
```

`index` finds the *first* occurence of the value.  Your desired output depends on knowing *which* index you have.  Instead, keep track of both value and index:

```
for x_idx, x in enumerate(a):
    for y_idx, y in enumerate(b):
        if x == y:
            if x_idx == y_idx:   # This uses the current index
```